# Django + Daphne + Caddy + File Upload = 413 Error

Tags: proxy, python, webserver, django

I have a Django web application that is deployed, production, with Caddy. IN production, I use Caddy as a reverse proxy pointing to daphne which is pointing to my Django app. However, when I try to upload a file to the admin portal in production I get a 413 error. In debug mode, when I am just using Django, I do not get this error. Anyone have any ideas? Here is my Caddyfile:

```
0.0.0.0:2015
on startup daphne peptidedb.asgi:application &

header / {
  -Server

    # be sure to plan & test before enabling
    # Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains; preload"

    Referrer-Policy "same-origin"
    X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"
    X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff"

    # customize for your app
    #Content-Security-Policy "connect-src 'self'; default-src 'none'; font-src 'self'; form-action 'self'; frame-ancestors 'none'; img-src data: 'self'; object-src 'self'; style-src 'self'; script-src 'self';"
    X-Frame-Options "DENY"
}

proxy / localhost:8000 {
    transparent
    websocket
    except /static
}

limits 750000000

log / stdout "{combined}"

errors stdout
```

asgi.py

```
import os

from channels.routing import get_default_application
import django

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "peptidedb.settings")
django.setup()
application = get_default_application()
```

wsgi.py

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "peptidedb.settings")

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add

```
DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE = 21474836480 # value in bytes 20GB here
```

to your settings.py